# how do i get to the GUI versions of the command line programs

Tags: windows-7

How do i get to these in Windows 7 in the graphical user interface?

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://206.74.58.18:8080/ user=everyone

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 8080" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8080
```

Comment: Through the Firewall settings...

Comment: I see the advfirewall one, but I can't find the http add urlacl?